# Yii 2.0 $request->post() issues

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In my controller I have the following lines

```
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    print_r($request->post());       
    echo "version_no is ".$request->post('version_no',-1);
```

The output is given below

```
 Array
    (
        [_csrf] => WnB6REZ6cTAQHD0gAkoQaSsXVxB1Kh5CbAYPDS0wOGodSRANKBImVw==
        [CreateCourseModel] => Array
            (
                [course_name] => test
                [course_description] => kjhjk
                [course_featured_image] => 
                [course_type] => 1
                [course_price] => 100
                [is_version] => 1
                [parent_course] => test
                [version_no] => 1
                [parent_course_id] => 3
                [course_tags] => sdsdf
            )

    )
version_no is -1
```

So here the return value of post() contains the  version_no.But when it is called as `$request->post("version_no")`, it is not returning anything (or `$request->post("version_no",-1)` returns the default value -1).

As per Yii 2.0 docs, the syntax is correct and should return the value of post parameter.

But why is it failing in my case.The post array has the parameter in it.But the function is not returning when called for an individual parameter value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your parameters are in `$_POST['CreateCourseModel']['version_no']` etc. with `$request->post('version_no',-1)` you trying to get `$_POST['version_no']` which is not defined so it returns you *-1*. So to get *version_no* use

```
$data = $request->post('CreateCourseModel'); 
print_r($data['version_no']);
```

Comment: Ok..But why the parameters are enclosed in an index with model name ?..Yii 2.0 docs never says anything like that ?

Comment: when you use `ActiveForm` it genereates input names like this _[modelClassName][attribute]_ if you did not specified it explicitly via  _[options][name]_ param

Answer (score 4):

You can access nested `$_POST` array elements using dot notation:

```
\Yii::$app->request->post('CreateCourseModel.version_no', -1);
```

Model properties are grouped like that for massive assignment that is done via `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`.

Depending on your needs maybe it's better use default value validator like that:

```
['version_no', 'default', 'value' => -1],
```